# Find $\int \frac{1}{x+x\log x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int \frac{1}{x+x\log x}\,dx$$

I couldn't use any of the integration techniques to solve this, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"HINT":** (Assuming of course that $\log=\ln$) It is $$\int\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+\ln x}\,dx$$ so you can make the substitution $y=\ln x$.

Comment: Do you mean dy = 1/x dx? And int 1/(1+y) dy is ln(1+y) = ln ln x??

Answer (score 3):

$$
\int \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+\log x}dx
$$
let $1+ \log x = u\implies du =\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\ln 10}dx$

then we have
$$
\int \ln 10\frac{1}{u}du = \ln 10 \ln u + C
$$

Comment: I should add that this answer assumes $\log$ is the common log.

Comment: @LanierFreeman Yes, because I was not sure if the user was talking about natural or base 10. In either case there are two answers covering both :).